How to enable the "enable auto-updates" link on installed plugin page?
I'm building a WordPress plugin and have implemented a custom update functionality using GitHub releases and transients. I’ve successfully deployed the plugin on GitHub and followed the steps mentioned in this guide.
The update logic is working as expected, but there’s one thing I’m trying to understand better. What action or filter is responsible for displaying the "Enable Auto-Updates" link on the Installed Plugins page?
When there's an update available for my plugin, I see the "Enable Auto-Updates" link. However, once the plugin is up-to-date, the link disappears. I’ve done some research but haven’t been able to pinpoint the exact hook that triggers the appearance of this link. Is it related to a specific attribute, and does it only show up when there’s an update notification in the transient response?
Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

you can do this with "update-supported" => TRUE on the output of this filter : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/update_plugins_hostname/

@mmm Thanks for your revert, But I'm not using update_plugind_hostname filter and I can't see any similar options with the filter pre_set_transient_update_plugins

you can see an example of the new way of doing this here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/426518/plugins-update-now-not-working-installed-in-folder-with-random-suffix/426550#426550

@mmm That's insightful, before I change the entire implementation I've one question, I t would be really helpful if you can advise. will this solution works if the plugin is hosted on github? or If I add the github repo url ro update URI attribute and $hostname will it work?

I tried the suggested way with github domain and it worked like a charm. Thanks for help @mmm
